# How to include a JS file in a NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, target, .net-standard

I need to create a .NET Standard 2.1 NuGet package that contains a JavaScript file which will be added to my consuming application in the following path:

> /wwwroot/js/myFileFromNugetPackage.js

(the consuming application happens to be a Blazor Server app)

I followed one [example](https://github.com/tiagoavila/NugetGeneratingFilesInDestinationProject) which used a *.targets file, but it didn't work for me.

The closest I got was to set up my NuGet project as follows:

1. Create a top level folder named "wwwroot"
2. Add the file "wwwroot/js/myFileFromNugetPackage.js"
3. In the properties for that JS file, set "Build Action = Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" = "Copy Always"

I publish this to my private NuGet library.

I then add that package to my Blazor (.Net Core 3.1) application.

When I look in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, what I see looks promising:

> /wwwroot/js/myFileFromNugetPackage.js

However...

If I manually create a new file in the same directory, so I now have:

> /wwwroot/js/manuallyAddedFile.js
>   /wwwroot/js/myFileFromNugetPackage.js

When I go to the properties of the two files, I see different paths:

> C:{some path}\MyApplication\wwwroot\js\manuallyAddedFile.js

and

> C:\Users\{me}\.nuget\packages\{myNuGetPackage}\{version}\contentFiles\any\netstandard2.1\wwwroot\js\myFileFromNugetPackage.js

And unsurprisingly, when I attempt to use either of those JS file using Blazor's JS Interop, I can use the one I manually entered, but it can't find the one from my NuGet package.  The F12 developer tools show only the manually created one present on the Client.

So, my question is: How do I set up my NuGet project to write a JS file so that it ends up in the correct directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And unsurprisingly, when I attempt to use either of those JS file
>   using Blazor's JS Interop, I can use the one I manually entered, but
>   it can't find the one from my NuGet package.

Because you can only in Blazor application (**new SDK format**) using [packagesreference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files), so you import package can only by reference links will be in the form of your files into the project in a package, so myFileFromNugetPackage. Js properties displayed in the path `../. Nuget/packages` .

**This is also a feature of the pacakgesreference nuget management format**. By the way, this is not such case with [packagesconfig nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config).

When you add a new item which means that you have created a file under your current solution, so you can find the new file under the solution.

> I followed one example which used a *.targets file, but it didn't work
>   for me. So, my question is: How do I set up my NuGet project to write
>   a JS file so that it ends up in the correct directory?

**Solution**

To solve your problem you can add a target file to the nuget package which copys the actual file to the project so that it will be referenced in the main project and not referenced in the link.

I tried your link demo and it can successfully achieve your goal.
The core is this paragraph

```
 <ItemGroup>
        <SourceScriptFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\scriptsToGenerate\*.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="CopyScriptsToProject" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceScriptFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\js\scriptsToGenerate\"
        />
    </Target>
```

**Note:**

*In some cases, you might want to add custom build targets or properties in projects that consume your package, such as running a custom tool or process during build. You do this by placing files in the form `<package_id>.targets` or `<package_id>.props` (such as Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff.targets) within the \build folder of the project.*

**This pre-processing target can only be executed at build time,
 So I suspect you can't find the JS file in the main project without building the project.** Hope it could help you.

Comment: As mentioned, it didn't work in my hands.  However, I revisited this approach and when I changed the name of my targets file, it started working (it hadn't matched the name of the project, although I'd referenced it in the PROJ file.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help. The name of targets file in nuget package should be the same as Package_ID(most of the time, it's also the project name), see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package). Will update the answer above with this info:)

Comment: One further point.  When publishing (to a folder with IIS) the JS file was not included.  I had to manually a) include it in the project, b) mark it as "Content" and c) make it "Copy Always".

Comment: It's the disadvantage if we use xx.targets file, we lose the feature from Content or ContentFiles element when we choose to use targets file :-(

Comment: Would you happen to know how to get this to work with core 6/7?  I tried the method you had said, and it doesn't work anymore.  If i try to just use the Content tag like i used to, it'll copy it into the contentFiles folder and then into the same named folder in the installed project.  If i use the Targets method in the project i install my nuget package into, it will work with the filepath to the system nuget installation folder, but not if i use the target method inside my nuget package.